Select(distinct()) Function in MySQL
Apologies, this is probably the easiest question you will get all day;
I am used to working in SSMS and have recently started to use MySQL. I am creating a new project and running the same queries I did on SSMS as I am on MySQL but it doesn't seem to run correctly. For example:
in MySQL, I am trying to find the distinct number of car models. The column is named car models. So I try that, and it says I "Have an eror in your SQL syntax". My query is this:
SELECT count(distinct(car model)) FROM ev_sales. 

Then I try count(distinct('car model')) FROM ev_sales. This works but it says that there is only 1, which is false.
I then try count(distinct(car_model)) FROM ev_sales. That says the column name isn't recognized.
It has something to do with the column name because if I want to run that query but with the word "city" it will do it fine. But anything that has a space in it, MySQL does not like for whatever reason. Any and all suggestions I would greatly appreciate it!

Use backticks, not single quotes.

If the name includes spaces use back-ticks (`) in My SQL.

And you'll make your life easier if you don't put spaces in your column names.

Why do you have brackets between DISTINCT and car_model?

DISTINCT is a keyword, not a function name, you don't need parentheses around the column name.

https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/mysql-count-tutorial/
